# How to obtain the following topology?

Tags: topology

My follow up question: [How can I use a pivot circle instead of a pivot point](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70294/how-can-i-use-a-pivot-circle-instead-of-a-pivot-point)

**Question**

At this moment, I have this:
[image]

What is the most efficient way to achieve a quad as *cut section*, where

- all the faces as well as the unselected vertices are duplicated and
  overlapping
- but share the same vertices (selected).

The *cut section* would look like this:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a torus with _Minor Segments_ set to 4, then scale along Z?

Comment: you may try with solidify modifier. You can, within that modifier choose a suitable thickness.

Comment: Would beveling a circle curve - or even a screw modifier - do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've severely misunderstood what you're trying to achieve, I still think a torus with *Minor Segments* set to 4 is the easiest and quickest way.

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>M</kbd> followed by <kbd>T</kbd> or *Add* -> *Mesh* -> *Torus* to add the torus.

[image: Add Torus]

After adding it and changing *Minor Segments* to 4, just scale along Z, <kbd>S</kbd> followed by <kbd>Z</kbd>, then type in the scale or drag the mouse, and finish with <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>LMB</kbd>.

[image: Scaled along Z]

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative 1**

I tried the following:

- <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude the selected vertices, <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd> and 0 to scale relative to the y-axis
- Then remove the doubles

**Alternative 2**

- First add a plane and rotate it 90 degrees around y-axis and rotate it 45 degrees around x-axis
- scale along z-axis

It could be a solution to my own question and hence I posted this as an answer to my own question, but perhaps you have a more efficient solution