# How can I use a pivot circle instead of a pivot point

Tags: topology

As a follow up question to my previous question:
[How to obtain the following topology?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70292/how-to-obtain-the-following-topology)

**Question**

I start the with topology that resulted from the previous question:
[image]

How can I use a pivot circle instead of a pivot point, so I can obtain the following (of course I did it manually and inaccurate), where the distances, highlighted with red arrows, are equal and blue circle indicates pivot circle:
[image]

**What I already tried**

I tried scaling the inner and outer circle and use keyboard to type the same value, x and 1/x respectively

Comment: One way could be just mirroring one of those outer rings with either modifier or interactive mirroring.

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of trying to find a way of changing pivot point mechanism (which doesn't necessarily exist) it's better to change way of modeling this object.

Simple alternative is to model this using curves. Create 2 curve circles, one - for the main object, another one - as bevel object for the first one. Set parameters for beveling on the first one and then make proper sharpness of second one to achieve form of desired object.

[image: screenshot-useless circles]
Both curve circles next to each other. Handle type for the big one is left as default, for the small one (profile curve) is set to *Vector* (edit it by pressing <kbd>V</kbd> in Edit mode)

[image: screenshot-curve-options]
Options for the big circle object (main one)

[image: screenshot-scaling-profile]
By editing profile curve you change main one. Note that if you want length of edges outlined on your screenshot to remain the same make sure to scale profile vertices (selected above) simultaneously or length will become uneven.

[image: screensnhot-converted-mesh]
Edges of the final mesh have the same length.

See related info here [Extrude along path](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2866/extrude-along-path)

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative**

- First add a plane and rotate it 90 degrees around y-axis and rotate it 45 degrees around x-axis
  [image]
- scale along z-axis
  [image]
- move the plane along the z-axis up
- use *screw modifier* with *angle: 360* and *screw: 0*

I know I answered my own question because this could be an alternative to my question, but it does not answer my question about pivot circle